# ng-repeat object undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

List of events:

```
export class HomePage {
  private socket = null;
  private event_list = [];
  constructor(public http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.event_list = [{"payload": {"action": "create", "pk": 667, "model": "photogallery.image", "data": {"confidence": "93.62", "detect": false, "description": "a gate in front of a fence", "timestamp": "2017-09-12T17:26:43.029Z", "image": "gallery/PICT0609_X4Fpw9D.JPG", "detect_type": null, "device": 1}}, "stream": "intval"}]
```

Then repeating events in template:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="event in event_list">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="img/thumbnail-totoro.png">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{ event.payload.data }}</h2>
    <p>{{ event.payload.data.description }}</p>
    <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Then error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined

But in template when I just do {{ event }} it shows in template:

```
[object Object]
```

So why is it undefined??

Comment: Try and use `{{ event?.payload?.data }`

Comment: Are you getting `event` object from async function like ajax?

Comment: Yes, I can do for loop repeat and above works with JS code

Comment: Hi Rahul - that still only shows [object Object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Ionic 2. use `*ngFor` instead of `ng-repeat`

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let event of event_list">
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
      <img src="img/thumbnail-totoro.png">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <h2>{{ event.payload.data }}</h2>
    <p>{{ event.payload.data.description }}</p>
    <button ion-button clear item-end>View</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: I didnt realie that I am using angular 4... and ionic 3... Thanks, this worked! Should delete my question..